# Calculate multiples $var on get_post_meta

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm new to PHP and appreciate any help. I'm trying to understand why $skill is not working on get_post_meta on Wordpress.

I'm trying to calculate (sum) all meta fields numbers in each meta fields = 'ecpt_editorial', 'ecpt_branding', etc. (i.e. = 'ecpt_editoral' has 3 points in one post + 4 points in another one.)
I'm trying to calculate them all without need to create a $ to each of them (they're too many).

My errors:
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in

```
 <?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'   => 'post',);
        $points = get_posts( $args );   
        $total = 0;

        $skill = array ('ecpt_editorial','ecpt_branding', 'ecpt_packaging');

        foreach( $points as $point ) {
            $single = get_post_meta( $point->ID, $skill, false );
            $total += $single;}

       echo $total;
       ++$total;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant pass in a array to the $key field. This is prob what your looking for:

```
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'   => 'post',);
    $points = get_posts( $args );   
    $total = 0;

    $skill = array ('ecpt_editorial','ecpt_branding', 'ecpt_packaging');

    foreach( $points as $point ) {
        foreach($skill as $key){
             $single = get_post_meta( $point->ID, $key, false );
             var_dump($single);
             echo '<br>';
            ${$key} += (int) $single;
        }
   }

   foreach($skill as $key){
       echo $key.'='.${$key}; // there are now 3 variables with count values set, $ecpt_editorial , $ecpt_branding, $ecpt_packaging
   }
```

assuming your not looking to save $single for use?

Comment: Hi David! 
I don't need $single, but I need to sum all $single, does that make sense? I'm getting error: Unsupported operand types on line $total += $single;

Comment: wierd....you sure you've got numbers in all those fields? i updated something just to make sure!

Comment: No, actually many of fields are blank. Still getting the same error. Let me try to explaining again: I fill each 'ecpt_x' option metabox in each post. If it's '0' I don't fill anything. I would like to sum all values in all 'ecpt_x' metabox. Like: 
ecpt_editorial = 2 + 2 + 0 = 4 and ecpt_branding = 0 + 2 + 5 = 7. Sorry for messy explanation.

Comment: i think i understand see above for the changes you should have 3 different counts there. I also type cast the return value as a interger so that should take care of the error!

Comment: David, thanks for your help, but it didn't work either. I'm getting as result: 'ecpt_editorial=ecpt_branding=ecpt_packaging='
should I change something on code?

Comment: try it now, if it doesnt work look though the values its var dumping and see whats there..